# Session folder not generated in magento 1.8

Tags: magento, session

I m working in magento 1.8 unfortunately it stopped creating session file in session folder.can any one please help me on this.

https://www.screencast.com/t/fXFrjDPHnq4G

Comment: Is your configuration set to keep sessions in the file system (rather than REDIS for example?) - has your `var` folder got adequate permissions to allow the creation of the session folder?

Comment: yes everything setup for save session in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes finally got the answer myself.

It was due to set session save path on local.xml

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    <!-- <session_save_path><![CDATA[/tmp/session]]></session_save_path> -->
```

Just commment out path variable and it seem to working fine again.

Thanks